# searching for a solution to write log file pg restore

Tags: windows, postgresql

I get an conflict error with -d and -f together, do you have a solution ?

> pg_restore -d mydb -h myhost --clean --verbose c:\dba\Manager\tk\Tasks\import-tk-21aug2022\budget-app-sara-21.8_updated_withdata -f c:\dba\manager\tk\restore-tk-21aug2022.log

Comment: Could you show the error, please?

Comment: 1) Yes don't use them together 2) Read the docs [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) where you will find that `-f` is for 'restoring` the database to a file as text and  `-d` if for restoring to the server. You have to choose one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

`-f` is not for a log file. `-f` says instead of restoring the dump to a database, write a SQL script which will do the restore.

`-d` says to restore the dump to the given database.

They say to do two different things, so they conflict. You have to decide which one you want to do.

See the [pg_restore docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html).

Comment: I want to see what pg_restore has done in a log file

Comment: @meirben I'm not sure what you mean by "what pg_restore has done". If you want to capture the output from the program, use [shell output redirection](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/input-output-redirection-in-linux/).

Comment: i simply want to capture what pg_restore has done, like every log file. You directed me to a Linux solution but I'm working on Windows 10

Comment: "Capture what it has done" as in what it prints to the screen? Please clarify that so we can better answer. If so, there's no special option in pg_restore for that, you're expected to use output redirection. Even on Windows, it just might work a little different.

Comment: "Capture what it has done" as in what it prints to the screen? " Yes ! exactly. like log file of every kind of job